# Maven build order (Multiple modules)

Tags: java, maven, build

I have a Maven parent project which has multiple child/modules...I have the following pom.xml for the main/parent;

```
<modules>
        <module>Main-Ear</module>
        <module>Sub-Web</module>
        <module>Sub-Ui</module>
        <module>Sub-Services</module>
        <module>Sub-SSO-Login</module>
  </modules>
```

However, I find the actual build order to be different...
After build, the actual order looks like;

```
Main
Sub-Services
Sub-SSO-Login
Sub-UI
Sub-Web
Main-Ear
```

Where exactly does Maven take the build order from in this case?

Answer (score 13):

You can't manually control the build order:

From Maven project documentation ([Guide to Working with Multiple Modules](http://maven.apache.org/guides/mini/guide-multiple-modules.html)):

> **Reactor Sorting**
>
> Because modules within a multi-module build can depend on each other,
>   it is important that The reactor sorts all the projects in a way that
>   guarantees any project is built before it is required.
>
> The following relationships are honoured when sorting projects:
>
> - a project dependency on another module in the build
> - a plugin declaration where the plugin is another modules in the build
> - a plugin dependency on another module in the build
> - a build extension declaration on another module in the build the    order declared in the  element (if no other rule applies)
>
> Note that only "instantiated" references are used -
>   dependencyManagement and pluginManagement elements will not cause a
>   change to the reactor sort order

Answer (score 5):

`Maven` not taken the module building order from  what we define in the main `pom.xml`. `Maven` decide the order by considering module dependencies with each other modules.

In your case definitely `Main-Ear` should build last.

Let's consider following example.

I have module `A`, `B` and `C`. Module `A` has dependency from module `C` and `B` while module `C` has dependency from module `B`. Then `maven` building order will be

```
B
C
A
```

Comment: So, u are saying there would be no explicit declaration anywhere in pom.xml...but Maven takes the decision on it's own..based on dependencies....

Comment: @testndtv Yes.  I think (but I am not sure) it may still depends on the order you declare, if two sub-modules has no dependencies between them.  e.g. A -> C  and B -> C, then Maven may use order of declaration to determine which of A or B is built first

Comment: @AdrianShum If there is no dependencies between each other, then maven will use what ever order we define